# Direction of magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

How did we know that the direction of magnetic field is from north to south and not the opposite?
For example, we may use iron filings, and they will take the shape of the magnetic field, but how we knew it is from north to south and not the opposite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction of a magnetic field is arbitrary.
Some time ago it was noticed that magnetic materials aligned themselves in an geographic North  to South line.

The part of the magnetic material which point roughly towards the geographic North pole was called the north-seeking pole of the magnet which then became the the north pole of the magnet.

Faraday used the term lines of force for what we now call lines of magnetic field and at some stage it was decided that magnetic field lines go from a north pole to a south pole or have a direction which is the same as that of the force on a isolated north pole if such an entity exited.

So I "know" that the lines of magnetic field go from north to south only because everybody uses that convention.

Answer (score 1):

Repulsion is the surest test for Magnetism. For finding polarity of magnetism, this may help you:

http://m.wikihow.com/Determine-Polarity-of-Magnets